# How to emphasise a note in a group of notes in right hand?

Tags: piano, melody

I am planning to work on the No.5 Prelude and Fugue in F minor, op.35 by Mendelssohn. When I saw the score and then heard a performance, I noticed that the right hand is playing a series of chords of where the topmost note is emphasised.
   Any suggestions for exercises as to how to achieve this will be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The piece itself is a pretty good exercise for this.

Start by practising the right hand with just two "lines" of music - the tune and one note from the accompaniment. Try rotating your hand when you play the notes in the tune, so you get more downwards motion on your little finger.

You can also make it easier by playing more of the accompaniment notes with the left hand - for example the middle Cs in bar 1, the F's in bar 3, etc.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that I conceptualize is **"leaning" my hand towards the emphasized pitch**. For instance, if the uppermost pitch in my right hand needs to be brought out, I conceptualize leaning into the pinky finger of my right hand. The same is true if I need to bring out a middle voice; here I might find myself "leaning into" the thumb. (Note: this is precisely what alephzero mentions, he just uses the word "rotating.")

What's important, though, is to ensure that *all pitches still sound together*. It's very common for a young student to practice this "leaning into pitches" technique and have the emphasized pitch sound before all of the others. This is almost never ideal; make sure they still sound together!

Another practice tip is to **remove the non-emphasized pitches**, often resulting in a LH accompaniment and a single RH melody. In doing so, one is able to solidify their interpretation of the melodic line, making it easier for this to come across when the non-emphasized pitches are added in.

Similarly, I've found **singing the emphasized pitches while I play** also helps.

As always, **recording yourself is the best method of tracking your progress**. Often we *think* we're emphasizing a particular line, but then when we record ourselves and play it back, we realize just how much the emphasis is only in our heads, and not actually coming out in the music!

Answer (score 0):

Play the chord, then slightly lift the fingers on the keys you DON'T want emphasized. Hold it like that. Gymnopedie no. 1 is great for learning this with!